# How do I prevent my textview from pushing other views off screen?

Tags: android, layout

I am not sure why my layout is like this, if my book title textview is too long it pushes my entire layout offscreen and messes everything up.I already tried applying gravity as well as setting the weight to 1 of my textview but this is solves nothing. Could someone help me out? Thank you in advance.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookTitleTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/bookImage"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="false"

        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:text="A boy with tigers"
            android:textColor="#424242"
            android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bookTitleTv"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"

            android:text="by Georeg Lopeaa"
            android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
            android:text="@string/vertical_ellipsis"
            android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think Unequal weight distribution will solve this for you, its a quick read.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#prioritize-weight

Answer (score 0):

User fixed height like `android:layout_height="180dp"` or wrap content to take only the space necessary like `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your TextView.

Comment: Isn't that bad practice??

Comment: I wouldn't be using a set height, it won't adapt to different screen sizes.

Comment: It will adapt to different screens also if you use particular height and use this library to set height 

implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

Example
Use height like  android:height="@dimen/_40sdp"

Comment: @Samuel not necessarily. it depends on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using it is wrong. For using weight in linear layout please add some weightsum to its parent layout and use it properly Please use below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:weightsum="4"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bookImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookTitleTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/bookImage"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize = "end"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:text="A boy with tigers"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bookTitleTv"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="by Georeg Lopeaa"
        android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
        android:text="@string/vertical_ellipsis"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />
```

You can use weight in decimal also according to the view you want on your screen.Also make sure whenever you

1. use weight in case of vertical view keep height as 0dp so that it takes the 
   height according to weight assigned and
2. in case of horizontal view keep width as 0dp so that it takes the
   width according to weight assigned

Answer (score 0):

you can either use fixed height and width on the textview like so (Recommended):

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/secondLineTextView" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" 
/>
```

or just limit the character amount according to the size you want like so (Not recommended):

```
   <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:maxLength="10" 
        android:ellipsize="end"
     />
```